# How to add addtional class name on click, other than `mouseenter' in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I would like to add a additional class name to an element on click. how to add that?

I am trying this way, but not working:

here is  my code :

```
<div class="row designOption" ng-class="{'active':proDesign}" ng-class="{'activeShow':proDesignAdd}">
            <span ng-mouseenter="proDesign = true" ng-mouseleave="proDesign = false"  ng-click="categoriesAdd('proDesign')" class="icon iconD">D</span>
            <span class="info infoD">Design</span>
        </div>
```

Here i am shuffling the `active` and on click i need to add `activeShow` how to do that?

Comment: you can use :active pseudo property anyway if you want some css on active state.. why are you not doing it?

Comment: I want to change elements sibling not element

Comment: that is also possible using css. :)

Comment: Show me a sample.  let me save more time!

Comment: posted an answer :) check the plnkr link :)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to add a class on an element using selector.

```
$('selector').addClass("classname");
```

For your case, if you would like to add class for

```
<span ng-mouseenter="proDesign = true" ng-mouseleave="proDesign = false"  ng-click="categoriesAdd('proDesign')" class="icon iconD">D</span>
```

then try

```
    $('.iconD').click(function(){ 
         $('.iconD').addClass("activeShow");   
        // Or do whatever you wish to     
    });
```

For

```
<span class="info infoD">Design</span>
```

Try

```
    $('.infoD').click(function(){ 
         $('.infoD').addClass("activeShow");
        // Or do whatever you wish to     
    });
```

In both the cases, I have used one of the existing class on the span as selector.

Comment: For your case, I need to create the directives right

Answer (score 0):

Or without any Jquery, you can do like that :

**Html :**

```
<div class="row designOption" ng-class="{'active':proDesign , 'activeShow':proDesignAdd}">
   <span ng-mouseenter="proDesign = true" ng-mouseleave="proDesign = false"  ng-click="categoriesAdd('proDesign')" class="icon iconD">D</span>
   <span class="info infoD">Design</span>
</div>
```

You don't need to have 2 ng-class, one can be use to regroup all class you want to add.

**Controller :**

```
$scope.proDesign = true;
$scope.proDesignAdd = false;

$scope.categoriesAdd = function(value){
 //Do you stuff with value
   $scope. proDesignAdd = !$scope.proDesignAdd;
}
```

With your mouse enter/leave, you will manage the 1st css. With your click you will manage the second one with the changement of your boolean value.

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gx9c3fuj/)

Comment: In case if I use the `jquery` what would be the approach? using `directives`? - please confirm

Comment: As it's not really recommended, I'm never using Jquery with Angular so I'm not really helpful on this. I think the other answerer can help you more thant me.

Comment: Jquery has nothing to do with directives. Directives are an angularjs component. Also, i aggree with Apédémak: it isn't advisable at all to use jquery combined with Angular.

Comment: @radusezciuc  Yeah I know that thanks.... And I also know that in pure angular (like my solution), there is no need for a directive.... But he was asking for the best approach using Jquery. Using Jquery don't mean 100% Jquery, so yeah maybe in Jquery he has to use directive also, but I don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can always achieve this using css.

Check this fiddle

http://plnkr.co/edit/JZhWlkNAkTILswKUIEN4

```
  <div class="first-div"> 
      Active of this div
    </div>
    <div class="second-div">
      Change Color of this div
    </div>
```

css

```
div {

  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 100px;
}

div.first-div:active + div.second-div {

  background: red;
}
```

You need to make sure IE is running in standards mode - put in a doctype like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: Very nice solution. But not works even `ie10` do yo have any `hack` for that?